# Concatenate all except last two columns in R

Tags: r, paste

Is there a way to concatenate all the leading column values except for the last two in R ?

Below is a snippet of my dataframe

```
DISEASE Gender  Race    Freq    NEWCOL
Salmonellosis   M   RACE_LATINO_HISPANIC    1   NA
Salmonellosis   F   BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN  2   NA
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   3   NA
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   4   NA
```

The desired result obtained using concatenate inexcel

```
DISEASE Gender  Race    Freq    NEWCOL  Concat
Salmonellosis   M   RACE_LATINO_HISPANIC    1   NA  Salmonellosis M RACE_LATINO_HISPANIC
Salmonellosis   F   BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN  2   NA  Salmonellosis F BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   3   NA  Salmonellosis M WHITE
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   4   NA  Salmonellosis M WHITE
```

I tried paste in R but couldn't find a way to disregard the last two columns

Also the number of columns will change with every iteration in my application, so I need to have a function that disregards the last two columns instead of selection a couple of leading columns

Comment: Are you trying to `df$Concat <- paste0(df$DISEASE, " ",df$Gender, " ", df$Race)`?

Comment: Yes, I'm, but the catch is that for this very instance its concat of Disease, Gender and Race; in the next instance it could be just Disease and Gender

This is because this code is a part of a shiny app where in the user makes a selection and the result is aggregated

Comment: then maybe `df$Concat <- apply(df[ , 1:(ncol(df)-2)], 1, paste, collapse = " ")`

Comment: So would the `unite` function in `tidyr` be useful: `df <- tidyr::unite(df, Concat, DISEASE:Race, sep = " ", remove = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an elegant solution, but given your data, you can simply use `apply` and pass in your `data.frame` with the last two columns dropped off by dynamically referencing the number of columns.

```
df = readr::read_table2("DISEASE Gender  Race    Freq    NEWCOL
Salmonellosis   M   RACE_LATINO_HISPANIC    1   NA
Salmonellosis   F   BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN  2   NA
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   3   NA
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   4   NA")

df$Concat = apply(df[,1:(ncol(df)-2)],1,paste,collapse=" ")
```

Answer (score 4):

The tidyr package has a handy `unite` function to perform this merge:

```
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, text="DISEASE Gender  Race    Freq    NEWCOL
Salmonellosis   M   RACE_LATINO_HISPANIC    1   NA
Salmonellosis   F   BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN  2   NA
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   3   NA
Salmonellosis   M   WHITE   4   NA")


library(tidyr)
answer<-unite(df, concat, -c("Freq", "NEWCOL"), sep = " ", remove=FALSE)

#or to select by only the number of columns
unite(df, concat, 1:(ncol(df)-2), sep = " ", remove=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `interaction`

```
df$concat <- interaction(df[head(names(df), -2)], sep= " ")
```

or `paste` from `base R`

```
df$concat <- do.call(paste, df[head(names(df), -2)])
```